# Squid error on bind9 start

Tags: server, dns, squid

I'm getting the following error after a bind9 update when I restart bind9 on my 12.04 LTS server:

```
root@server2:/etc/bind# service bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                                                                    
status: Unknown job: squid
waiting for pid 14728 to die    [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9              
status: Unknown job: squid
```

I've haven't noticed this before. I have squid3 and named running on the server without any issues that I can see. Bind seems to be trying to invoke squid?

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because the service name of squid is 'squid3', not 'squid' in any squid configuration file.
I did this:

```
apt-get remove --purge squid

apt-get install squid
```

And it works.